# Using LESS with node.js

Tags: node.js, less

Less is amazing and I want to use to node.js because using less.js is not a good performance. I testing purpos i'm using xamp on windows and I install node.js but where and what i should write.. I install express.js `npm install -g express`  and less `npm install -g less`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're using expressjs you can install

```
npm install less-middleware
```

and then in your application (app.js)

```
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
```

then you have to tell expressjs to use less-middleware by doing

```
app.configure(function(){
  //other configuration here...
  app.use(lessMiddleware({
    src      : __dirname + "/public",
    compress : true
  }));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

now in your [appname]/public/stylesheets/custom.less

gets translated into regular css custom.css

Comment: I thought I had to compile .less using cli each time I was testing... until I saw this answer. Thanks for introducing the middleware!

Comment: It's almost TOO EASY to use, this way. :)

Comment: So useful... I wonder why less-middleware wasn't mentioned in the docs (or in a place I couldn't find?)

Comment: In http://www.amazon.com/Node-js-Action-Mike-Cantelon/dp/1617290572/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1377710078&sr=8-1&keywords=nodejs+in+action it goes through middleware and some about expressjs! @KhanhNguyen

Comment: In case someone else has the same problem I did: make sure you're referencing the `.css` file in your layout and not the `.less` file.  If you reference the css file it will automagically be compiled for you (even if it doesn't exist on disk yet).

Comment: Better to define your dependency in package.json: `"less-middleware": "latest"` then `npm install` to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @gravadlax "npm install less-middleware --save" is the correct way to do it. It adds "less-middleware" to the package.json file for you, with the current. "less-middleware" : "latest" will not work well on a team, as whenever someone npm installs, if a new version is released, that team member will have different versions of the dependency.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using express 4.x and less-middleware 0.2.x beta (which is the latest at the moment), the syntax is a bit different.

This is the same:

```
$ npm install less-middleware
```

But the middleware has a `source` and three option parameters:

```
function(source, options, parserOptions, compilerOptions)
```

Example:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')(
    __dirname + 'public/style/less', // source
    { dest: __dirname + 'public/style/css' }, // options
    {}, // parser
    { compress: 'auto' } // complier
));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The complier's auto compress is really nice, `style.css` will result in an uncompressed and `style.min.css` will give you a compressed file.

For more info you should check out the Migration guide and the source code here: https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware

Comment: Cheers for that, only just realised the accepted answer is 2 years outdated.