# Where is the compiled CSS of a Less file stored?

Tags: css, browser, less

I use Less with my site. Let say the code look like below.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.3/less.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

When I updated the styles.less file, and refresh the page, Less.js will compile the less file and apply to the page. But I just wonder where is the compiled CSS file stored? Does less.js call `lessc` to compile the less file?

Answer (score 1):

In the setup you gave (the HTML page), you are letting the client to worry about interpreting the *Less* file.

To be exact, Browser loads the JavaScript library you link to, and then this JavaScript interprets the `styles.less` file.

The actual css file is not stored on the server, as it is all the browser-sided work, and I doubt the browser stores it somewhere except RAM.

---

This does not sound like a good approach though. We, generous site owners with high-end servers love to lift the computational bit off the clients as much as possible. We do not want to upset an iPhone user running low on battery without neccessity.

Alternatively, you run `lessc styles.less > styles.css` on your styles file after you finished editting. And then use `styles.css` in HTML directly, also remove the `less.js` from HTML.

---

Question you might want to ask: *How do I make compiling to css automatic then?*

There are several solutions:

- Automate the compilation of *less file* on it being changed, using some software to watch a file or directory.
- The Editor you are using might have *compile less* feature, or be added as an extension.
- You might want to consider strat using a web framework. It is an overkill for just compiling less, but if you get other advnatages from web framework or are already using it - that is a good option. An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219637/using-less-with-node-js) of using Less middleware with Express framework.

Comment: You don't really need a whole framework just to process LESS files automatically. It's mostly an issue of using the right editor, or setting up some other sort of *watcher* which automatically compiles the file every time you change it. Moving everything over to some framework just for that is a bit overkill. The file just needs to be compiled once during development, not on the web server.

Comment: @deceze fully agreed with you. I meant that he might want to start using web framework, as its other advantages might also help him depending on what he is doing. Modified the answer, to give better overview of automation options. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @alandarev Thanks your post ,You said `the client interpreting the Less file`. I am not sure what it mean, Does it mean the browser interpreting the Less file ? If it does,I am not agree with you. In my understanding .If I use less.js. The work of compile less should happen in the server. because I only install the nodejs in the server. not necessary to install the less package for all kinds of the clients . And the server will return the compiled css code for the Less file http request. Is that right ? please help to verify it .thanks.