# How do I compile LESS files every time I save a document?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, less

I've installed Less via npm like this

```
$ npm install -g less
```

Now every time that I want to compile source files to .css, I run

```
$ lessc styles.less styles.css
```

Is there any way via the command line to make it listen when I save the document to compile it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution out there I've found is the one recommended on the official LESS website: https://github.com/jgonera/autoless. It is dead simple to use. Also it listens to the changes in the imported files to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/less-auto-compile/

It offers GUI solutions (SimpLESS, WinLESS, LESS.app, and ChrunchApp) and a node solution. (deadsimple-less-watch-compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using less alone or with Node.JS ? Because if you are using it with node, there are easy ways to resolve this problem. The first two I can think of are (both these solutions go in your `app.js`) :

- using a middleware, like stated in this [stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219637/using-less-with-node-js)

  ```
  var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
  ...
  app.configure(function(){
      //other configuration here...
      app.use(lessMiddleware({
          src      : __dirname + "/public",
          compress : true
      }));
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  });
  ```
- another method consists of making a system call as soon as you start your nodeJS instance (the method name may differ based on your NodeJS version)

  ```
  // before all the treatment is done
  execSync("lessc /public/stylesheets/styles.less /public/stylesheets/styles.css");
  var app = express();
  app.use(...);
  ```

In both cases, Node will automatically convert the less files into css files. Note that with the second option, Node was to be relaunched for the conversion to happen, whereas the first option will answer your need better, by always checking for a newer version in a given directory.